# Compare string to previous and consecutive row to check if alphabetical order

Tags: python, pandas

I need to check if a column in a dataframe is in alphabetical order comparing only the two adjacent values.

| idx | Col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |
| 4 | A |
| 5 | B |
| 6 | B |
| 7 | C |

or:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['A','A','B','A','A','B','B','C'], columns=['Col1'])
```

Now only row 2 is out of order.

I'd like to do something like:

```
df['InOrder'] = df['Col1'].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x[0] >= x[1] >= x[2])
```

But rolling only works for numerical values.

I've also tried:

```
df['InOrder'] = df['Col1'] >= df['Col1'].shift(1) >= df['Col1'].shift(2)
```

But I get

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

This is what I expect to get:

| idx | Col1 | InOrder |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | True |
| 1 | A | True |
| 2 | B | False |
| 3 | A | True |
| 4 | A | True |
| 5 | B | True |
| 6 | B | True |
| 7 | C | True |

P.S.: Since I have other columns and I need to keep the data in current row order.

Comment: The error that you get is because when you compute `df['Col1'] >= df['Col1'].shift(1)  >= df['Col1'].shift(2)` this gets evaluated as `(df['Col1'] >= df['Col1'].shift(1))  >= df['Col1'].shift(2)` (note the brackets) 
In order for this to work correctly you should do: `(df['Col1'] >= df['Col1'].shift(1)) & (df['Col1'].shift(1)  >= df['Col1'].shift(2))`
However, due to `NaN` handling, this may not give you the result you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one idea with [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) and `np.diff`, replace missing values anf compare by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) for great or equal:

```
df['InOrder'] = df['Col1'].rank(method='dense').rolling(2).apply(lambda x: np.diff(x)).fillna(0).ge(0)
```

Or similar like @wwnde solution:

```
df['InOrder'] = df['Col1'].rank(method='dense').diff().fillna(0).ge(0)

print (df)
  Col1  InOrder
0    A     True
1    A     True
2    B     True
3    C     True
4    B    False
5    D     True
6    D     True
7    E     True
```

EDIT: If need match up to 1 value is possible use:

```
df['InOrder'] = df['Col1'].rank(method='dense').diff().shift(-1).fillna(0).isin([0,1])
print (df)
  Col1  InOrder
0    A     True
1    A     True
2    B    False
3    A     True
4    A     True
5    B     True
6    B     True
7    C     True
```

---

```
df['InOrder'] = df['Col1'].rank(method='dense').diff(-1).fillna(0).isin([0,-1])
print (df)
      Col1  InOrder
0    A     True
1    A     True
2    B    False
3    A     True
4    A     True
5    B     True
6    B     True
7    C     True
```

Comment: This solved the problem partially. In fact, in my case, this propagates the error down 1 row (if i get A, A, B, A, B, B, D, C) - both the first B and the D are incorrect. But that's a problem different from the one I stated and I guess would be much harder to solve.

Comment: @TiagoDuque - Ok, so need for  `D` also False? I think it should be possible, need time for test.

Comment: For better understanding: I have an automatically processed dictionary. Some words were incorrectly processed and hence should be manually reviewed (there's a correct series of a words with a b word in the middle - the b word is incorrect, and followed by more a words). I should be able to detect words that are out of order both related to previous or next. Your solution already gives me a way to see that there's a problem, but will be offset by 1.

Comment: @TiagoDuque - Can you test now? Need Falses for index=4,5 ?

Comment: @TiagoDuque - So it means need shifting differenct up to one value? And test if difference is 0 or 1? Added solution to answer.

Comment: @TiagoDuque - hmmmm, more complicated I think, maybe necessary convert words to letters and then processing.

Answer (score 2):

Convert them into numerals using astype category. Find the consecutive differences and anything less than 0, make it false. Code below

```
df['InOrder']=df.Col1.astype('category').cat.codes.diff(1).fillna(0).ge(0)




    Col1  InOrder
0    A     True
1    A     True
2    B     True
3    C     True
4    B    False
5    D     True
6    D     True
7    E     True
```